# keras autoencoder resource exhausted error

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I have a dataset where the number of samples is 25000 and number of features is 24995. I am trying to train an keras autoencoder model on this data and facing OOM error. Some specifics of the model are

```
Input matrix shape : (25000, 24995)
```

This input matrix is divided into validation set as training and testing data.

```
Train Matrix shape : (18750, 24995)
Test Matrix shape : (6250, 24995)
```

The code for training is

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
input_layer = Input(shape=(train_matrix.shape[1],))

encoding_hlayer1_dims = 12500
encoding_hlayer1 = Dense(encoding_hlayer1_dims, activation='relu', trainable=True, name="layer1")(input_layer)

decoding_hlayer1 = Dense(train_matrix.shape[1], activation='relu')(encoding_hlayer1)

autoencoder = Model(input_layer, decoding_hlayer1)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

The summary of the model is

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 24995)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
layer1 (Dense)               (None, 12500)             312450000 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 24995)             312462495 
=================================================================
Total params: 624,912,495
Trainable params: 624,912,495
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Code to train the model

```
## Train
history = autoencoder.fit(train_matrix.toarray(), train_matrix.toarray(),
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=64,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(test_matrix.toarray(), test_matrix.toarray()))
```

When I start training the mode, I get the following error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24995,12500]
     [[Node: mul_3 = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](beta_1/read, Variable/read)]]
```

I am using 2 Nvidia Tesla K40c Gpu's with 12G each. As per my knowledge, the model should fit in memory as 25000 * 12500 * 2 = 0.625 GB. Also, the input matrix dtype is numpy.float32.

Can anyone point out what exactly am I doing wrong here ?

Update: Complete error log

```
Train on 18750 samples, validate on 6250 samples
Epoch 1/100


ResourceExhaustedErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-503b20168fa5> in <module>()
      6                 batch_size=4096,
      7                 shuffle=True,
----> 8                 validation_data=(test_matrix.toarray(), test_matrix.toarray()))
      9 #     autoencoder.save("/tmp/Models/sae_models/epochs_" + str(epochs) + ".model", include_optimizer=True)
     10 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
   1428                               val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
   1429                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics,
-> 1430                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1431 
   1432     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch)
   1077                 batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
   1078                 callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
-> 1079                 outs = f(ins_batch)
   1080                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1081                     outs = [outs]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2263                 value = (indices, sparse_coo.data, sparse_coo.shape)
   2264             feed_dict[tensor] = value
-> 2265         session = get_session()
   2266         updated = session.run(self.outputs + [self.updates_op],
   2267                               feed_dict=feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in get_session()
    166     if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:
    167         with session.graph.as_default():
--> 168             _initialize_variables()
    169     return session
    170 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in _initialize_variables()
    339     if uninitialized_variables:
    340         sess = get_session()
--> 341         sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(uninitialized_variables))
    342 
    343 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    787     try:
    788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
    790       if run_metadata:
    791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    995     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    996       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 997                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    998     else:
    999       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1130     if handle is None:
   1131       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1132                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1133     else:
   1134       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1150         except KeyError:
   1151           pass
-> 1152       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1153 
   1154   def _extend_graph(self):

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24995,12500]
     [[Node: layer1/kernel/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@layer1/kernel"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](layer1/kernel, layer1/random_uniform)]]

Caused by op u'layer1/kernel/Assign', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-ee2fe8e92d7c>", line 4, in <module>
    encoding_hlayer1 = Dense(encoding_hlayer1_dims, activation='relu', trainable=True, name="layer1")(input_layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 569, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 825, in build
    constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 391, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 321, in variable
    v = tf.Variable(value, dtype=_convert_string_dtype(dtype), name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 200, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 309, in _init_from_args
    validate_shape=validate_shape).op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 271, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 45, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24995,12500]
     [[Node: layer1/kernel/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@layer1/kernel"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](layer1/kernel, layer1/random_uniform)]]
```

Comment: Can you show the full error message? And also could you tell how do you run this script? Do you run it from console or e.g. `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: `decoding_hlayer1_dims` is unused.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Added the full error message. Also, I run it in jupyter notebook.

Comment: @JonasAdler I am planning to build a multi layer autoencoder by freezing this layer's weights. So the variable will be used in next layer training.

Comment: Well it is unrelated to this question and should be removed from it

Answer (score -1):

The total number of parameters is `624,912,495` as per your code. That should take `624912495 * 4 / 1024**3 = 2.32` GB just to store the weights (not 0.625 as you computed).

In addition to this, you need to store the initializer and at least another 3 copies for the optimizer, one for the first and second order momentum respectively, and one for the actual update, not to mention some temporaries to store computations since anytime you write `a + b`, you need memory to store that, and there likely is some hidden.

Overall you quickly find that the total memory use is far above 12 GB, which is why you run out of memory.

You could try using a SGD optimizer which uses less memory, but you may still run out.

Comment: That was helpful information. I have 2 GPU's both of which are k40c with 12Gigs. So, in theory I have 24G of memory and the model should be able to fit into memory. Why am I getting the memory issue still? Is the model not being distributed across the gpu's or am I not specifying it in the code.